# Checkboxlist Event on change the state C#

Tags: c#, checkboxlist

In c# I have a checkboxlist. Now I want to do something each time the state of one of the checkboxes changes (so from checked to unchecked or from unchecked to checked).
Which Event do I need for this? The problem is that a simple clickEvent doens't work because it's like I need to click twice on a checkbox to check or uncheck it. (it first selects it, and just then it checks or unchecks).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event your looking for is SelectedIndexChanged:

[ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) or [Winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

Comment: That trows also an event on the first "select" click... (It only have to work on the second click when I check or uncheck the checkbox)

Comment: I don't understand what you're after here. First you say you "want to do something each time the state of one of the checkboxes changes". Then you say "It only have to work on the second click". Which is it? Every time or the second time?

Comment: See my posted answer, the property CheckOnClick has to be True, otherwise you need to click twice to check or uncheck.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: Your link is for ASP.NET, i assume OP wants [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) instead(see his comment above).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes. His comment stated ASP.NET. That has apparently now been changed to Winforms.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event.
Look at : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx)

Comment: I only see the SelectedIndexChanged event, and that trows also an event on the first "select" click... (It only have to work on the second click when I check or uncheck the checkbox)